# Does there exist a surjective homomorphism from $(\mathbb R,+)$ to $(\mathbb Q,+)$ ?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism, infinite-groups

Does there exist a surjective homomorphism from $(\mathbb R,+)$ to $(\mathbb Q,+)$ ?  ( I know that there 'is' a

'surjection' , but I don't know whether any surjective homomrophism from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb Q$ exist or not . Please help . Thanks in advance )

Comment: Assuming the axiom of choice yes. Not sure if it does without it.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft : Assuming choice , do you mean anyway by Hamel-Basis ?

Comment: Yes, pick a basis and project to the first coordinate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure.

Fix a Hamel basis $B$ for $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q$, fix some $r\in B$ and map $B\setminus\{r\}$ to $0$, and $r$ to $1$. Then you're done.

If you want to avoid the axiom of choice, you can't. It is consistent that every homomorphism from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb Q$ is continuous, and therefore its image is connected. But this means that every homomorphism is $0$.

(This is a consequence of "Every set of reals is Lebesgue measurable" as well "Every set of reals has the Baire property", at least in the presence of Dependent Choice. Both of these have been shown consistent with Dependent Choice by Solovay starting with an inaccessible, and later Shelah proved that for the Baire property you do not need an inaccessible cardinal.)

Comment: geeze , what a case it is if we don't assume choice ..; could you please add some references of the results you have quoted ? Thanks in advance

Comment: This is actually an old theorem of Banach. If $f\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, and $f$ is Lebesgue measurable then $f$ is continuous. You can do the same proof with functions being Baire measurable (preimage of open sets have the Baire property). Under the stated axioms (every set of reals ...) it is trivially the case. So if you require the range to only contain rational numbers it has to be $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint** Write $\mathbb R$ as a vector space over $\mathbb Q$. Pick a basis $B$ and define a vector space homomorphism by sending $B$ to $\{ 1\}$.

Show it has the desired property.

**Second solution** Use Zorn's Lemma to define a maximal homomorphism from a subgroup of $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb Q$ which is identity on $\mathbb Q$.