# There doesn't exists an epimorphism from $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ to $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ proof verification.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Suppose that such epimorphism exists, and call it $f$.

For fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}$, take $N = \text{Ker}(f)$ and $S = x\mathbb{Q}$.

Apply the second theorem of isomorphisms, that is:
$$(SN)/N\cong S/(S\cap N) $$
But $(SN)/N = \{\text{Ker}(f)\}$, so that $S/(S\cap N) = \{ x+S\cap N: x\in S\} = \{ S\cap N \}$, hence $S = S\cap N$. This means that $S\subset N$, from which follows that $$\mathbb{R} = \text{Ker}(f)$$So that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, hence $f$ is not an epimorphism, and contradiction proofs that such epimorphism cannot exists.

Is this proof correct? Did I miss anything? Can it be done easier? Thank you.

Edit: Sorry, I see now that this proof isn't correct. Clearly, $NS$ doesn't have to equal $N$, which I thought is true because of additive and multiplicative notation confusion.

Comment: You seem to be mixing multiplicative and additive notation. Both groups in the headers are additive abelian groups, thus...what is $\;S=x\Bbb Q\;$ ? Is it really all the rational products of $\;x\;$ ? But then why $\;SN\;$ and not $\;S+N\;$ ? All this is confusing...

Comment: @DonAntonio: note that $\{qx\mid q\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ is an *additive subgroup* of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Jakobian: I cannot figure out why you conclude that $(SN)/N$ is a single element. That holds if and only if $x\in N$, *which is your desired conclusion*, so it looks to me as if you are assuming what you are trying to prove. How do you justify that $(SN)/N$ consists only of $N$?

Comment: It's all because I've mixed up additive and multiplicative notation. Sorry for that, I was sligthly confused myself.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I know that, yet the the notation $\;SN\;$ seems off for additively written groups. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *is* an epi $(\mathbb R,+) \rightarrow (\mathbb Q ,+)$. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1637405/does-there-exist-a-surjective-homomorphism-from-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-q), especially the answer by N.S.

Comment: Thank you. I was convinced it doesn't exists.